# CSS - Remove rotateX for child elements

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have the following tab. 
[image]

The code for it is.

```css
.nav-tabs li a {
  color: $color_1;
      -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
      -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
      height:32px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border:1px solid #ccc;
      margin:0 10px 0;
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px  #fff inset;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      
     <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       Some text</span></a>
     </li>
     <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       Some Text</span></a>
     </li>
     <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>Some Text</span></a>
     </li> 
   </ul>
```

The issue is the text 'Some text' inside the tab is inheriting the rotate property from its parent. How to remove the rotate property for the text.

I tried giving **transform-style: preserve-3d** to the parent and gave **transform: rotateX(-30deg)** to the text span. But it isn't working. Can someone kindly help.

Comment: Rotating the child text **should** be the right way...if it's not working you need to demo it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, added Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I suspect the issue was that the `span` elements weren't set to `display:inline-block` as transforms to do not affect inline elements.

I also had to set a height on the spans equal to that of the anchors but that seems a minor issue.

```css
.nav-tabs li a {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
  height: 32px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff inset;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  color: red;
}
.nav-tabs li a span {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       Some text</span></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       Some Text</span></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>Some Text</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transform: none !important
-webkit-transform: none  !important;
-moz-transform: none !important;
-ms-transform: none !important; /* FOR IE*/
```

The `!important` declaration will override all previous `transform` attributes

Comment: Please do mention the reason for down voting :) Helps me improve

Comment: No idea except you clearly haven't read the question carefully. Setting `transform:none` on the child will do nothing to solve the OP's issue.